# How can I remove (not hide) an Angular child element from DOM when it raises an event?

Tags: angular

I am creating a list of child elements via `*ngFor` directive (not with ComponentFactory)
Something like this:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <top-menu #topmenu *ngFor="let menu of menus" (onDeleteMe)="handleDeleteMenu($event)">
  </top-menu>
</ul>
```

now I want `handleDeleteMenu` to remove the component from the DOM. Is this possible as is? Or should I change the template to create the components with the component factory?

Comment: Do you mean remove from DOM, or remove the item completely from the array used in your ngFor? The difference is removing from just the DOM will allow you to add it later, removing from the array will remove it forever.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @Z.Bagley. I want to keep the ability of re-adding it, so yes, just from the DOM

Comment: For sure. The method in my answer follows this method. Note that when you reference an element in your html you don't use `this` handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in the index of the ngFor iteration to your onDeleteMe method

```
<top-menu #topmenu *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index" (onDeleteMe)="handleDeleteMenu($event, i)">
```

Then splice out the iteration in your method

```
handleDeleteMenu(event, index){
    this.menus.splice(index, 1);
}
```

This will remove that specific iteration from your array and re-render the ngFor. Here is a demo plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/qphEdumLB7Eenb3FPtL5?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add an extra div, an index in the ngFor, and add an ngIf into the inner element,:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index;">
     <top-menu
       #topmenu
       (onDeleteMe)="handleDeleteMenu($event);showMenu[i]=false;" 
       *ngIf="showMenu[i]">
     </top-menu>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

And in your component typescript add a show index in an onInit:

```
showMenu = []
ngOnInit() {
  for( let i = 0; i < this.menus; i++ ) {
    this.showMenu.push(true);
  }
}
```

You could also just add a new object to `this.menus` instead of creating `showMenu`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. But first you should not give like `this.menus` . It should be `*ngFor="let menu of menus"`.
In `handleDeleteMenu()` function pop the element from the `menus` array. The `ngFor` directive will automatically rerenders with new array of elements.

Answer (score 0):

*ngIf removes dom element from dom tree but you cannot use *ngFor and *ngIf in same tag. You can create another tag and place *ngIf and inside that you

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <div *ngIf="menus && menu.length > 0">
    <top-menu #topmenu *ngFor="let menu of menus" (onDeleteMe)="handleDeleteMenu($event)">
    </top-menu>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Also in your code this.menus will will just menus as its in the view not in component class

Comment: the OP needs to remove only the specific element that was clicked.

Comment: real the last part of the question, now I want handleDeleteMenu to remove the component from the DOM. Is this possible as is? Or should I change the template to create the components with the component factory?

Comment: he want to remove the chield component from the done not any specific element from the iteration. also the question title is removing the dom element not array element.

Comment: understand the question again sir :)

Comment: @Faisal The question is unclear. The title says remove a child component, but then he requests what sounds like removing DOM (as opposed to using `hidden`), but he might also be looking for splice().

Comment: that is true. edit this question so that I can upvote :)

Comment: @Faisal, you can edit the question as well. But let the user who asked the question to edit it and let him to clear what he actually want ;)